# How to disable menu button and the action bar still remains there

Tags: android

I have a problem in disabling menu button , I dont want the menu button to be enable , I disable is by returning `false` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` function , but it hides all action items in my action bar, so How to disable menu button without affecting my actionbar?

Comment: What menu button are you taking about? Is it a hardware menu button? Is it the overflow (three vertical dots) button on the ActionBar? Or is it the overflow icon that appears on the navigation bar next to the Recents button?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention , I mean a hardware one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hardware menu button is not controlled by `onPrepareOptionsMenu().` Generally speaking, it is not good practice to change the behavior of hardware buttons because users expect it to behave a certain way (which I believe is to expand the overflow menu).

If you absolutely have to disable it, you could listen for it to be pressed in our Activities like this:

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    final int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
    final int action = event.getAction();
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        return true; // consume the key press
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: But what about else statement ? what I have to return? false or true?

Comment: False. Returning true consumes the key press.

Comment: Does this False affect other hardware buttons?

Comment: Actually, you should return super.dispatchKeyEvent(). My mistake.