# How can I disable the hardware menu button in my app?

Tags: android

My app has an Activity that needs 'back' and 'menu' hardware buttons disabled. I disabled the 'back' one with `onBackPressed` but I have no idea how to disable the menu button.

Comment: Override the Menu Key like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202165/overriding-the-physical-menu-button-on-android

Comment: Be careful, this can totally break the user experience.

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the key event [onKeyDown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29). That worked for me.

There is a [KEYCODE_MENU](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) you can catch.

Answer (score 0):

in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
   final int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
   final int action = event.getAction();
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        return true; // consume the key press
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Credits to [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15732036/375929)

Answer (score 0):

Update your Gradle files for the app, so you have a current  compileSdkVersion,buildToolsVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. 
Then update your Gradle files for the project so you have the current classpath for Gradle, for instance 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'. This solved the problem for me. I tried the solutions suggested above, but they did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this question in my activity through override onKeyUp(if keyCode is KeyEvent.Menu return true)