# How to redirect a activity to its previous activity when home button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-navigationview

I am developing a parental control app. I need to restrict bottom navigation button usages , some how I restricted Menu and Back button usages butI couldn't restrict home button usage , I came to know that home buttons cannot be restricted (Correct me If I am wrong..!) so I need to redirect to the previous activity when Home button is pressed. I tried Lots of methods (Some of them are below)

1.[Can I override the 'Home' button in my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547818/can-i-override-the-home-button-in-my-application)

2.[How can I disable the hardware menu button in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384120/how-can-i-disable-the-hardware-menu-button-in-my-app)

3.https://abhik1987.wordpress.com/tag/android-disable-menu-button/

These are recommended by most of the people yet it doesn't work for me.

If any one got better alternate solution kindly notify me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can receive a broadcast after clicking home button,and then you can direct your activity to main activity,but you can't stop android enter launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like so. 
In the activity that was open before home pressed override the onResume() method. In it

```
Intent blockUserFromComingBack = new Intent(ActivityUserWasOnVeforePressingHome.this, HomeActivity.class);
ActivityUserWasOnVeforePressingHome.this.startActivity(blockUserFromComingBack);
```

This would allow activity to run an onStart but if it ever Pauses "such as the user presses home" when it resumes it will navigate user to the home activity.